# How can i implement stopwatch that can run both in foreground and background in react native expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, background-process, stopwatch

I am able to implement stopwatch in foreground but not sure how can i have it running in the background when i minimize or switch to another app. Does anyone have any solution for this?

Comment: Hi, you may use a variable to store the start time. So if the user leaves the app and comes back to it, you can actualise the app thanks to your variable (no need to run a process in the background, just perform an initial subtraction when the app become active). Does this answer your question?

Comment: @AdrienKaczmarek Yes i tried with your solution and it worked. Thank you.